# Disconnect command not working in discord bot, error when running

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, disconnect

So I'm trying to code a discord bot, but whenever I try to get it to disconnect, the following error comes up:

```
Ignoring exception in command leave
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\new\main.py", line 31, in leave
    await voice_client.disconnect()
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 297, in disconnect
    yield from self.ws.close()
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 419, in close
    yield from asyncio.shield(self.close_connection_task)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 686, in close_connection
    yield from super().close_connection(force=force)
TypeError: close_connection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: close_connection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force'
```

I've tried changing around how I get the bot to disconnect, but it just doesn't seem to want to go through with this line:

await voice_client.disconnect()

Here's the code that's not working.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

BOT_PREFIX = ('!')
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    if voice_client:
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        await client.say('Disconnected')
    else:
        await client.say('I am not in a voice channel')
```

Comment: Make sure your discord.py is updated to the latest.  Run `pip show websockets` and check the version, it should be `6 <= version < 7`

Comment: Sorry, for the async version, which you appear to be using the requirement is `websockets>=3.1,<4.0`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you alter your code such as:

```
voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
print(voice_client)
print(dir(voice_client)) # show available methods/attributes of the object
```

In order to double check that the `voice_client` object is what you expect it to be. From [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voice) I see no `.voice_client_in()`. However there is a [`VoiceClient.is_connected()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_connected) which returns a boolean. More in line with your code though is [`Client.voice_clients`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.voice_clients) which returns a list of ALL voice chats that are connected. So in your case this return value would look like:

```
if list_of_chats_connected:
    await list_of_chats_connected.disconnect()
```

which wouldn't make sense, since the list would need to be indexed to be able to call a method of the object inside it like `disconnect()`

Comment: They're using the 0.16.12 version: [`Client.voice_client_in`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.voice_client_in)